# Reducing dataframe in Geopandas using X and Y by averaging out other values

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a huge spatial dataframe with 1,4M entries, with X and Y columns. This causes SKlearn random forest algorithm to memory-overflow (32GB RAM)

I'd like to decrease the size of the dataframe to about 350K (or less) entries, with all other values being averaged out spatially. For example, to turn these 4 into a single dataframe row (ignore the fact that Y values are the same, it should be 2 unique X and 2 unique Ys)

```
               X           Y       dose        mezo        hght  
141668  -8773.349057  30004.7125  12.750189  156.410492  182.800507
141669  -8746.650943  30004.7125  12.742241  156.200867  182.364288   
141670  -8719.952830  30004.7125  12.742241  155.998550  181.934616   
141672  -8666.556604  30004.7125  12.729473  155.926254  181.166870
```

This data is going to be fed into sklearn's RandomForest classifier and be used to predict based on other data.

Comment: As for your memory issue, that is a lot of entries so maybe you can try altering the data types of the values in your DataFrame. That's what I usually do for extremely large datasets.

Comment: Ive already changed dtype for floats from float64 to float16, but it doesn't seem to be helping much.

Comment: Such type of reducing can distort your data distribution. I do not know how it is important for your aims. What do you want to do? And why is this a `GeoDataFrame` if **X**, **Y**, & **hght** are not unified into `Point` objects?

Comment: You're right, Vovin, I do not use geopandas in this program yet, it's a holdover from another program, where I merged geographic data into a single dataframe. But, I'm wondering if it can be used here to reduce data.

Comment: Hi Yan - welcome to stack overflow! It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're asking for help with. How do you want to reduce the data? are you just looking to groupby each set of four and average? if so, something like `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 4).mean()` should do the trick. Or are you looking for some sort of spatial grouping? if so, please clearify exactly how you're hoping this would work, and what you've considered and tried. If you're unsure and are looking for help approaching the problem, then this becomes a theory question and is probably a better fit for [gis.se].

Comment: if you want to cluster spatially before grouping and averaging - I'd suggest checking out [scipy's clustering package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html), e.g. [k-means](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans)